# Get child element using xpath selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, parent-child

We can get a parent of a selenium element using xpath, by

```py
par_element = element.find_element_by_xpath('..')
```

In a similar fashion, how can we get the child of the element? I tried the following and did not work

```py
child_element = element.find_element_by_xpath('/')
child_element = element.find_element_by_xpath('//')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get to the child of the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) you need to set the context to the current element using the dot character i.e. **`.`**. So effectively your line of code can be either of the following:

```py
child_element = element.find_element_by_xpath('./')
```

or

```py
child_element = element.find_element_by_xpath('.//')
```

Comment: I did not think of this, but it did not work.

Comment: sorry about that, it worked. I had an extra slash inside the xpath. Updated